# How do you print values in lists with their index number in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, random, indexing

I am trying to make a Blackjack game in python. I ran into a problem because I am trying to use the random module with my game. I used the random module to get a number that coordinates with the index number in my list. The list I made consisted of card face values. I don't know how to print these values using the random index number, though. Here is my code:

```
# this is a blackjack game made in python
import random
import time

# make a list full of the card values
cards = (["A", "K", "Q", "J", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

indexNum1 = random.randint(0,12)
indexNum2 = random.randint(0,12)
indexNum3 = random.randint(0,12)
indexNum4 = random.randint(0,12)
indexNum5 = random.randint(0,12)

for card in cards:
    print card(indexNum1)
    print card(indexNum2)
    print card(indexNum3)
    print card(indexNum4)
    print card(indexNum5)
```

I hope someone can help me solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: thank you AChampion. how would i use this in the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can index `cards` directly, e.g.:

```
print(cards[indexNum1])
```

But if you want in a loop you should iterate over the indexes:

```
for cardidx in (indexNum1, indexNum2, indexNum3, indexNum4, indexNum5):
    print(cards[cardidx])
```

But you are making this much harder than you need to, because currently your code could return `5` Aces - which I assume you don't want:

```
cards = ["A", "K", "Q", "J", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
hand = random.sample(cards, k=5)
for card in hand:
    print(card)
```

Comment: However it is possible to get 4 aces from a normal deck. For full realism you'd have to build a whole deck, literally `shuffle` it and make pops from the top of the deck. Alternatively you could add `* 4` to the end of the `cards` definition to make your code work.

Comment: True but creating a full deck is fairly easy with `itertools.product()`, e.g. `cards = itertools.product(["A", "K", "Q", "J", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], ['H', 'S', 'D', 'C'])`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to properly simulate a deck of cards, you'll have to do this:

```
import random

def clean_deck():
    return list("AJQK234567890") * 4

def draw_cards(deck, n):
    return [deck.pop() for _ in range(n)]

deck = clean_deck()
random.shuffle(deck)

for card in draw_cards(deck, 5):
    print(card)
```

This keeps track of the deck of cards, literally `shuffles` them, which is conveniently a `random` function, and then "draws" from the deck (`pops`). You have to keep track of the deck so you could, for example, draw 4 aces but then there wouldn't be any more left. This approach is also persistent across card-drawings - when you draw cards from the deck, they are actually removed, so you also can't draw more than 4 aces in an entire game. It will crash if you try to draw from an empty deck, although you could put an `if` statement in `draw_cards` to refill the deck if needed, but you should be aware that this would happen if the deck ran out - it could lead to weird things like 5 aces in a game.

I've changed all your digits to strings, as there's no use for them as integers if some cards aren't integers. (An alternative is to keep them all as integers, which you can do with the `range` function - at a guess `range(13)`, or if you want to go from 2, `range(2, 15)`). I've also changed `10` to `0` as `0` was unused and that made it a lot more concise. It should be easy enough to change back should you wish.

The difference between this and the other approaches is that the other approaches never remove cards (`pop`). They just randomly pick cards and then put them back, although they've been drawn.

Comment: Now how would I be able to add those printed card values together

Answer (score 0):

If you want to randomly choose k cards without repetition and keep the indices, this may helps:

```
import random

cards = (["A", "K", "Q", "J", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
indices = random.sample(range(len(cards)), k=5)
print 'Indices are:', indices, '\nCards chosen are:',[cards[index] for index in indices]
```